# Clustered index on last_update_at timestamp

Tags: mysql, normalization

- I have a Votes table , which can be considered a wrapper.
- I have a sub_items table, which holds one votable item. One Vote has many sub_items. On sub_item is owned by only one Vote.
- I have a Vote_actions table, that will record what changes were made to the STRUCTURE of a vote/or it sub_items.
- I have a table called Vote_casts , which will hold which user voted on which sub_item.

My service will need long-polling (so constant db checking every second or so).

And votes is not the only dynamic thing that I have. Therefore I decided to create a GENERAL_ACTIONS table, which will hold if some kind of action was performed on any of my modules (e.g. of a module is Voting). If there is some action performed, then my poller will look up my Vote_actions table IF some sort of structural change was made to the Vote, and it will look up the Vote_cast table, if a voting was performed, my GENERAL_ACTIONS table will have enum values like "Action_cast_vote","Action_updated_vote_structure".

For action_cast_vote as well as action_vote_structure I will be creating a clustered index on (timestamp,group_id,user_id,vote_id/sub_item_id,id).

I am doing this because I need to order by timestamp to get the newest rows that have just been added.

In my opinion, this table will work for long polling. If there is a brand new row added just after I had last checked, this means there is no way that the client knows of it.

But, say the user wants to SCROLL (it will be lazy loaded). User scrolls up, 50 entities are loaded. If he scrolls up again, 50 new entities are loaded etc.

I will do this by a query like :

> GET 50 NEWEST VOTES WHERE TIMESTAMP IS OLDER THAN X

My *Actions_table* will not be efficient for this. This is because a Vote might have been already loaded, but still have actions performed at an older time. In that case, the same Vote will be loaded up and sent again. But my client already has that data.

To fix this I want to create a table called Vote_scrollable. It will hold information about when a Vote (or sub item, or if somebody cast a vote) was last updated. By doing this I have a certainty that there is nothing newer/or older for that vote. If A vote has, say, Y time as last updated, I can be sure that SOMETHING was done to that vote.

Now if my user scrolls up, I would run a query like :

> GET 50 NEWEST VOTES FROM SCROLLABLE TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP IS OLDER THAN X

Again, I will create a clustered index on timestamp, because I need it to be ordered and limited to 50.

My questions are:

- Is this design extremely flawed? If so, what are they, and how may I fix them?
- Is is okay to have a clustered index on a value that will be updated fairly often? (I have given a vague idea about voting. Users can vote on items/ revote on items/ perform CRUD on sub_items, etc. All these actions will cause update on updated_at timestamp value, which is clustered index of the vote_scrollable table.)
- Any tips, help, suggestions etc. are much appreciated.

Comment: Try to write out the `SELECT` statements you will need.  This exercise, by itself, may help you answer many of the questions.